# Why i'm getting error: «Unable to locate a class or view for component []» from composer package?

Tags: laravel, laravel-8

I'm trying to require [spatie/laravel-honeypot](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-honeypot) and when navigating to the page where the component should be rendered, I get the following error: `Unable to locate a class or view for component [honeypot]` I cleared all caches, ran the command: `composer dump-autoload`, but it didn't help. But if i'm trying to get registered blade components by following code `Blade::getClassComponentAliases()`, i get the following output:

```
array:5 [▼
  "dynamic-component" => "Illuminate\View\DynamicComponent"
  "orchid-icon" => "Orchid\Icons\IconComponent"
  "orchid-popover" => "Orchid\Screen\Components\Popover"
  "tabuna-breadcrumbs" => "Tabuna\Breadcrumbs\BreadcrumbsComponent"
  "honeypot" => "Spatie\Honeypot\View\HoneypotComponent"
]
```

Why am I getting the error anyway?

Answer (score 1):

Wow, Just seeing this;

If you're using `<x-honeypot />` in your form, replace it with @honeypot